# How can i make a contract receive payment from a particular address and hence forth that same wallet address can't make payment to the contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, sendtransaction

i know the question may sound silly but I'm relatively new. I'm trying to make a contract to receive payment from a particular wallet address just once and henceforth that address that made the payment won't be able to make transactions to the contract.

i hope the explanation was clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store information about which contracts have sent payment already and which have not. If an address tries to send assets again, you can revert the transaction.

Here's a draft version:

```
contract Demo {
  mapping(address => bool) public received;
    
  function receiveOnce() public payable {
    require(!received[msg.sender], "You can only send once");
    received[msg.sender] = true;
  }
}
```

Note that the above example doesn't for example check *how much* value they sent. But hopefully it helps you to get started.